# HTML paragraph isnt going into a straight line

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm kinda new to programming and I cant solve this problem. The paragraphs are coming out like a stair case.

```
    p
   p
  p
 p
p
```

The p's are examples, but here is all the code I have done so far.
Keep in mind I'm not the best at css(I'm still learning)

All help would be appreciated

Please show me on how I an fix this problem, and tell me where in my code is this problem occurring.

I tried google but couldn't find anything...

```js
var house = {}
function House() {
 var msg = 'This house is painted'
 var bath;
 var bed;
 var cook; 

 var Paint = document.getElementById('paint').value;
 var square = document.getElementById('Square').value;
 var bath = document.getElementById('bath').value;
 var bed = document.getElementById('Bed').value
 var cook = document.getElementById('Cook').value;
 //Get paragraphs to store values
 var paint = document.getElementById('isPaint');
 var squareFeet = document.getElementById('sq_Feet')
 var bathRoom = document.getElementById('bathroom')
 var bedRoom = document.getElementById('BedRoom')
 var kitchen = document.getElementById('kitchen');

 if(Paint == 'Yes' || Paint == 'yes') {
  house['isPainted'] = true;
  paint.innerHTML = msg;

 }
 else if(Paint == 'No' || Paint == 'no') {
  house['isPainted'] = false;
  var msg = 'this house is not painted'
   paint.innerHTML = msg;
 } 
 else if(Paint == '') {
  house['isPainted'] = undefined;
  var msg = 'no details given';
  paint.innerHTML = msg;
 } 
 if(square != '' ) {
  var squareFeetMsg = 'the house is';
  squareFeet.innerHTML = squareFeetMsg + ' ' + document.getElementById('Square').value + ' square feet';
  house['squareFeet'] = document.getElementById('Square').value
 }else {
  var squareFeetMsg = 'No Details Given';
  squareFeet.innerHTML = squareFeetMsg;
 }
}
```

```css
body {
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
}
#houseDtails{
 width: 350px;;
}
#container {
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
}
.houseDetails {
 height: 0px;
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>House App</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="conatainer">
 <div id="houseDtails">
   <label for="paint">Is this house painted: </label><br>
   <input type="text" id="paint" class="Detail" /><br>

   <label for="Square">How many SQ feet does this have? :</label>
   <input type="text" id="Square"><br>

   <label for="bath">How many bathrooms does your house have</label>
   <input type="text" id="bath"><br>

   <label for="Bed">How many bedrooms dos your house have</label>
   <input type="text" id="Bed"><br>

   <label for="Cook">Does your house have a kitchen</label>
   <input type="text" id="Cook"><br>

   <input type="submit" name="" id="sub" class="subm" onclick="House()">
 </div>
 <div id="addDetailsToPage">

  <p id="isPaint" class="houseDetails"></p>
  <p id="sq_Feet" class="houseDetails"></p>
  <p id="bathroom" class="houseDetails"></p>
  <p id="Bedroom" class="houseDetails"></p>
  <p id="Kitchen" class="houseDetails"></p>

 </div>
</div>
 <script src="House.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't believe I understand what you'd like this to look like.  Do you have an example?

Comment: yeah i want them to be aligned one under the other?

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the paragraphs rendering in that manner is result of `float` set on `.houseDetails`.

```
.houseDetails {
    height: 0;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have `float: right;` in your CSS for `.houseDetails`. Remove it and you should have your `p` aligned on the left below one another